# Set Moq CallBase to be true by default

Tags: testing, moq, abstract

See here for why I want to have CallBase set on my Mock objects:
[How to use moq to test a concrete method in an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691796/how-to-use-moq-to-test-a-concrete-method-in-an-abstract-class)

It would be nice not to have to set this on every one of my mock objects.

Is there any way to set this globally?
e.g. some syntax like `Moq.Settings.CallBaseDefault = true` that I can put in my `[TestSetup]` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution Amol suggests is more or less built into Moq already.

If you use:

```
MockRepository factory =
        new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Loose) { CallBase = true, };
```

then code like:

```
var mock = factory.Create<Concrete>();
```

will create a loose mock with `CallBase` true.

(It does not make sense to set `CallBase` *property* to true for `Strict` mocks. For them, do an explicit `mock.Setup(x => x.MemberToUse).CallBase();` for each class member (method or propery) where you want it.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if such a setting would be available out of the box.
I would suggest to wrap `new Mock<Concrete> { CallBase = true };` in a factory.

```
public static class MockFactory
{
    public static Mock<T> Create<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new Mock<T> { CallBase = true };
    }
}
```

And while creating mocks simply use:

```
var mock = MockFactory.Create<Concrete>();
```

Comment: In the absence of a built-in solution this seems pretty sound.